# Confusion using gdaltranslate.exe when rasters overlap

Tags: raster, gdal, r-raster, terra

I'm confused about what gdaltranslate is doing here. My understanding is that files are written on top of each other. So the last file, file_b, with 5 NAs in it should be present in the final tif. But the NAs aren't, the values 95,96,97,98,99 are.

```r
library("terra")
library("glue")

a <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, vals = 1:100)
writeRaster(a, "file_a.tif")

b <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, vals = c(1:95, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
writeRaster(b, "file_b.tif")

raster_list <- c("file_a.tif", "file_b.tif")

list_for_vrt <- "vrt_list.txt"

lapply(raster_list, write, file = list_for_vrt, append = TRUE)

vrt_file <- "temp.vrt"

system(glue('{double_quote("C://Program Files//QGIS 3.26.1//bin//gdalbuildvrt.exe")} -b 1 -q -input_file_list {double_quote(list_for_vrt)} {double_quote(vrt_file)}'))
system(glue('{double_quote("C://Program Files//QGIS 3.26.1//bin//gdal_translate.exe")} -q -co {double_quote("PREDICTOR=2")} -co {double_quote("COMPRESS=LZW")} -of GTiff -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS {double_quote(vrt_file)} {double_quote(gsub(".vrt", ".tif", vrt_file))}'))

rast("temp.tif") |> setMinMax() |> minmax()

    temp
min    1
max  100
```

Where have the NAs gone?

Finally, my goal here is that I want to take the max value of overlapping rasters. So I want to reliably be able to do that (in the way that seems to be happening here, but I'm not sure why).

If I flip things around, gdaltranslate *does* seem to write the second file over the first one.

```r
library("terra")
library("glue")

a <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, vals = 101:200)
writeRaster(a, "file_a.tif", overwrite = TRUE)

b <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, vals = c(1:100))
writeRaster(b, "file_b.tif", overwrite = TRUE)

raster_list <- c("file_a.tif", "file_b.tif")

list_for_vrt <- "vrt_list.txt"
unlink(list_for_vrt)

lapply(raster_list, write, file = list_for_vrt, append = TRUE)

vrt_file <- "temp.vrt"
unlink(vrt_file)

system(glue('{double_quote("C://Program Files//QGIS 3.26.1//bin//gdalbuildvrt.exe")} -b 1 -q -input_file_list {double_quote(list_for_vrt)} {double_quote(vrt_file)}'))
system(glue('{double_quote("C://Program Files//QGIS 3.26.1//bin//gdal_translate.exe")} -q -co {double_quote("PREDICTOR=2")} -co {double_quote("COMPRESS=LZW")} -of GTiff -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS {double_quote(vrt_file)} {double_quote(gsub(".vrt", ".tif", vrt_file))}'))

rast("temp.tif") |> setMinMax() |> minmax()

    temp
min    1
max  100
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related, maybe I can use this to always take the maximum of any overlapping bands: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html#vrt-that-adds-2-or-more-rasters . Can anyone help me with the syntax?

Comment: I had a go with gdalwarp: https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/a13462d300514192b5ce18a6183e5c31  - changed a few things idiomatically, I'm still unsure about the NA/max thing you're asking about. I'm not sure what a complex source in VRT does when put through gdal_translate, but I understand the warper.